# how to determine if variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

in another question on SO, I was determining how to toggle off a function, and the working solution is this:

I place `var disabledFlag = true;` in the head section of my page and before calling shell.js, then in shell.js I have:

```
/*******************************/
/*  TOGGLE BUTTON
/*******************************/
var toggleBlock = function() {
    console.log(disabledFlag);
    if(!disabledFlag){
      var windowsize = $(window).width(),
      isDesktop = windowsize > 765;
      $("#quicksearch").toggleClass("collapse in", isDesktop);
      $("#quicksearch").toggleClass("collapse out", !isDesktop);
      $("#sidebar").toggleClass("collapse in", isDesktop);
      $("#sidebar").toggleClass("collapse out", !isDesktop);
    }
    else {
      $("#quicksearch").addClass("collapse out");
      $("#sidebar").addClass("collapse out");  
    }
}
$(document).ready(toggleBlock);
$(window).on("resize.showContent", toggleBlock);
toggleBlock();
```

shell.js is an common file that is shared with other sites and may not have the variable defined. how do I check if the variable is defined, and if not assign it to false and then execute the code above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are easier ways to do it than using ternaries or `if else` statements.

As far as your specific function goes, you could do something like this:

```
var toggleBlock = function() {
    var disabledFlag = disabledFlag||false;

    if(!disabledFlag){
    //etc.
```

`undefined` is falsy, so it works with the logical `||` operator.  That `||` operator makes the new `var disabledFlag` be set to `disabledFlag` (if it exists), and if not, it will set the `var` to `false`

This same concept is used in many different contexts.  For example:

**Situation 1 -**

```
var obj = {hello: 'world'};

function fn(object) {
    var object = object || {foo: 'bar'};

    return object;
}

fn(obj)  //  ==> {hello: 'world'}
```

**Situation 2 -**

```
function fn(object) {
    var object = object || {foo: 'bar'};

    return object;
}

fn(objectThatDoesntExist); //  ==> {foo: 'bar'}
```

In JavaScript libraries and module-pattern projects, this concept is used quite frequently in many different ways.

Comment: mehhh still not working, what your saying makes sense so i have no idea why this isnt working

Comment: this is magically working now. i am assuming that server level cache expired. we automatically generate htmlc files in each instance and once it expried, this started working.

Answer (score 6):

try

```
if (typeof disabledFlag === 'undefined')
    disabledFlag = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `typeof`

```
if (window.disabledFlag === undefined) window.disabledFlag = false;
```

Comment: added if (disabledFlag === undefined) {
   var disabledFlag = false; 
}; and still not working

Comment: Don't use `var`.  That makes the variable local to the scope it's in, the if block.  You want it attached to window.

Answer (score 0):

you can check if a variable is undefined with the `typeof` keyword, like this:

```
if(typeof neverDeclared == "undefined") //no errors

if(neverDeclared == null) //throws ReferenceError: neverDeclared is not defined
```

take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) for more info on `typeof`